# Intro slider next button cutting off flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Picture of the next/done button being cut off]

As you can see in the picture the next button is not there. I have no clue what is wrong since i measure the height and width of the device with `MediaQuery.of(context).size`. I left the code inside a paste bin any help is appreciated.

https://pastebin.com/LYgytDkr

https://pastebin.com/GuzyzPXQ

EDIT:
This bug only finds place on a samsung a50 as far as we know. We haven't encountered this bug on any other device yet

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `widthDoneBtn` value from `IntroSlider`,

I tried to replicate your problem but my code is running fine.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:intro_slider/intro_slider.dart";
import "package:intro_slider/slide_object.dart";

class Tutorial extends StatefulWidget {
  Tutorial({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TutorialState createState() => new TutorialState();
}

class TutorialState extends State<Tutorial> {
  List<Slide> slides = new List();
  Size screenSize;
  double buttonWidth;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  /// When tutorial is done.
  void onDonePress() {
    // TutorialHelper.setTutorialStatus(true);
    // Navigator.push(
    //     context, new MyCustomRoute(builder: (context) => OverviewPage()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // buttonWidth = screenSize.width / 3;
    slides.clear();

    slides.add(
      new Slide(
          title: ('OFFERS'),
          marginTitle: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          description: ('tutorial_offers'),
          marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          pathImage: 'assets/wp_logo.png',
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 130, 255, 1.0)),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
          title: ('AVAILABLE OFFERS'),
          maxLineTitle: 2,
          marginTitle: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          description: ('tutorial_available_offers'),
          marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          pathImage: 'assets/wp_logo.png',
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 130, 255, 1.0)),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
          title: ('SAVED OFFERS'),
          maxLineTitle: 2,
          marginTitle: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          description: ('tutorial_saved_offers'),
          marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          pathImage: 'assets/wp_logo.png',
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 130, 255, 1.0)),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
          title: ('PROFILE'),
          marginTitle: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          description: ('tutorial_profile'),
          marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          pathImage: 'assets/wp_logo.png',
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 160, 255, 1.0)),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
          title: ('EDIT PROFILE'),
          marginTitle: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          description: ('tutorial_edit_profile'),
          marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          pathImage: 'assets/wp_logo.png',
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 160, 255, 1.0)),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
          title: "CHAT",
          marginTitle: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          description: ('tutorial_chat'),
          marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          pathImage: 'assets/wp_logo.png',
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(132, 200, 255, 1.0)),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: IntroSlider(
          isShowSkipBtn: true,
          slides: this.slides,
          onDonePress: this.onDonePress,
          nameNextBtn: ('next'),
          nameDoneBtn: ('done'),
          // widthDoneBtn: buttonWidth,
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yeah sorry i sould have added this in my post i will do that now. But the tutorial specifically doesnt work on the samsung a50. With my emulators it works also but only on the samsung a50 it doesnt. maybe its something with the target build since we still have that on sdk version 28 or its the screen resolution

Comment: I can't say about samsung a50, Android fragmentation is pain sometimes 